# How to pass data from api to a vue method

Tags: vue.js

I have the following data

```js
"meta": {
    "total_count": 17
},
"items": [
    {
        "id": 80,
        "meta": {
            "type": "",
            "detail_url": "",
            "html_url": "",
            "slug": "",
            "first_published_at": ""
        },
        "title": "some title",
        "image": {
            "id": 46,
            "meta": {
                "type": "wagtailimages.Image",
                "detail_url": "some url",
                "download_url": "/media/original_images/im.png"
            },
            "title": "im.png",
            "width": 100,
            "height": 80
        },
      }
    ]
```

Now if I try to get the width of an image inside :src attribute it works but if I try to pass it to a method it doesn't
, a snippet of the HTML code is:

```html
<li v-for="(item, index) in response_data">
  <a v-bind:href="item.meta.html_url">
    <div class="icon" :class="classObject(item.image.width,item.image.height)">
      <img v-if="item.image" v-bind:src="item.image.meta.download_url" alt=""/>
      <img v-else src="{% static 'images/logo-dummy.svg' %}" alt="logo-dummy.svg"/>
    </div>
```

where `classObject` is a method that compares the width and the height, I tried also to make it a computed property, the above code doesn't work but if for example I wrote

```html
<img v-if="item.image" v-bind:src="item.image.width">
```

I can see the width inside the `src` attribute, what am I doing wrong?
Edit: classObject code is the following

```js
     classObject: function (width, height) {
        if (width > height) return 'icon1'
          return 'icon2'     
      },
```

Comment: What does `classObject` look like? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the code now, and I know it's not working because the whole element is disappearing

Comment: Does the element disappear from the DOM?  If not, what's the html output?

Comment: Seems to work fine here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/9ukz50sm/. Use your browser's dev-tools to check for errors and to inspect the elements and their classes

Comment: it works Now!!! I'm sorry to bother you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I encountered was because sometimes there was no image at all, otherwise the code is correct so now I just check if there's an image like this

```js
<div v-if="item.image" :class="classObject(item.image.width,item.image.height)">
      <img v-bind:src="item.image.meta.download_url" alt=""/>
    </div>
```